App not updating once code was changed in app.js and problem with expo dev build
Basically every time I run the app on expo go on android after changing code nothing updates and it ends up just running the original code I either pulled from github or just the default code when you create a new app. Is the problem because I am running it in Expo go, if that's the case I have a problem with running on the development build it gives me error code. - CommandError: No development build (------) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first. I don't know what this means or what to do. By the way I am using npx expo start as the first command in the terminal.
I tried updating react scripts and saving the project, deleting reinstalling, stuff like that.
